# 'upper air' meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context, ambiguity

Here's a passage from *[Diana of the Crossways](https://books.google.com/books?id=4u0XAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA37)* by George Meredith. My question is: what does the 'upper air' mean?

My dictionary says it is about the upper layers of the atmosphere; but it would be too scientific for this context! I have two ideas: it might be just air from the above (?), or the word "upper" can mean the direction of the wind. (Would it be Northern wind then? Lady Dunstane lives in Surrey, and just before the paragraph "our breezy South-west" is mentioned, which "gives distantly a tower to view".)

> Yet Lady Dunstane herself could name the bank of smoke, when looking North-eastward from her summerhouse, the flag of London: and she was a person of the critical mind, well able to distinguish between the simple metaphor and the superobese. A year of habitation induced her to conceal her dislike of the place in love : cat's love, she owned. Here, she confessed to Diana, she would wish to live to her end. It seemed remote, where an invigorating upper air gave new bloom to her cheeks ; but she kept one secret from her friend.

Answer (score 3):

It means air at the top of hills, in contrast to the air at the bottom of valleys.

The previous paragraph starts

> The residence of Sir Lukin Dunstane, in the county of Surrey, inherited by him during his recent term of Indian services, was on the hills ...

*invigorating upper air* was not unique to Meredith.  Around the same time it was also [used by Frank R. Stockton in *A Borrowed Month*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=C-TfCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT651&lpg=PT651&dq=%22%20invigorating%20upper%20air%22&source=bl&ots=ajo6HdiWZF&sig=Bl2mGfrNOp6cKZuxdVWbI-gmiko&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjYkaWc8d3PAhVBBMAKHaocCU0Q6AEILTAE#v=onepage&q=%22%20invigorating%20upper%20air%22&f=false)